# How to check class property in order to start countdown timer when it's get value 

Tags: c#, winforms

I have winform application who read files and change, rename etc.
Every time the status change (change, rename, working... etc) the status show in appropriate label, sometimes the next files who need to handle come with delay of number of seconds and when it happens I want timer countdown who display the time until the next file will come.
In the main class I have the property (type double) who receives the time in seconds when the next file will come.
I want the timer start if an interval of more than five seconds.
And when its happen the property will get the number of seconds and the timer should read this double and countdown.
How can I check this variable all the time and when he gets a appropriate value the timer will start ?

Here is my class how gets the delaytime:

```
public class Delay
{   
    public event EventHandler _largeWait;

    public Delay(int numberOfSeconds)
    {
        _numberOfSeconds = numberOfSeconds;
    }

    public double _delayTime;

    public double _packetDelay
    {
        get { return _packetDelay; }

        set
        {
            _packetDelay = value;

            if (value > 5 && _largeWait != null)
            {
                _largeWait(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then at the place where i create the Delay instance: (after insert value into the delay variable)

```
_largeWait += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (_largeWait != null)
         {
             _largeWait(s, e);
         }
     };
```

the problem here is that this become recursion and i dont know why

Comment: Your recursion is at the `_packetDelay` getter. It should be `return _delayTime;`. BTW: Starting public Members with underscore is a bad style. "Pascal case" is the commonly used style there.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a setter instead of the short form and start the timer if >5s:

```
public class Delay
{
    public event EventHandler LargeWait;

    private double numberOfSeconds;
    public double NumberOfSeconds
    {
        get { return numberOfSeconds; }
        set
        {
            numberOfSeconds = value;
            if(value > 5 && LargeWait != null)
                LargeWait(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public Delay(int numberOfSeconds)
    {
        this.numberOfSeconds = numberOfSeconds;
    }
}
```

And then at the place where you create the `Delay` instance:

```
Delay delay = new Delay(sec);
delay.LargeWait += (s, e) => {
    timer.Tag = s; //s is the Delay instance
    timer.Start();
};
```

Comment: but from where the class define i cannot reach the timer

Comment: Then you can pass in a reference or throw an event you handle where it is reachable...

Comment: thanks but from the main GUI thread who can i check the Delay.numberOfSeconds and than start the timer ? maybe with delegate  who inform when Delay.numberOfSeconds != null ?

Comment: Do you create the Delay instance in a place (in the GUI thread) where you have access to the timer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8641/discussion-between-chrfin-and-user979033)